# Forcing 4 decimal places on a number without changing its type to string

Tags: php, json

I receive some data including a decimal number from an api in post request with `content-type:json`

among the posted data  , is a `Amount` parameters with 4 decimal places

```
{
  "Amount": 500.0000  ,
  "param1" : "value1" ,
  "param2" : "value2" 
}
```

after parsing the json

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data);
```

here is my output

```
array(3) {
  ["Amount"]=>
  float(500)
  ["param1"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  ["param2"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
}
```

the problem is I’m losing the decimal places on the Amount if they are zero

so instead of `500.0000` I get `500` , I know they are the same numbers mathematically  but I need to generate a hash from these posted parameters which requires me to have `Amount` as a float number with 4 decimal places exactly as posted in the first place

I can do something like

```
$data['Amount'] = sprintf('%0.4f',   $data['Amount'] );
```

but than it would convert the Amount into an string , which results in a invalid hash

```
array(3) {
  ["Amount"]=>
  string(8) "500.0000"
  ["param1"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  ["param2"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
}
```

I need my $data output to be

```
  ["Amount"]=>
  float(500.0000)
```

tried to run it throw floatval , lost the decimal zeros again !
I’m losing my mind over something so simple , any idea  how to solve this ?

*--------------- edit --------------------*

purpose of this hash is to verify the origin of request (making sure its my provider who is sending me this data )

they send me publicKey with the request , I should generate the hash with some of the params and compare it against that public key

In order to create the hash , I need to json_encode some of the received parameters and run them throw sha256  , at the end I need to compare them to a received public_key

so if I receive

```
{
  "Amount": 5000.0000,
  "Token": "6789",
  "OperatorId": 7799,
  "TransactionId": 110883669553,
  "PublicKey": "f7bb8448c5701b9530fbecc8f9d6296b2ce0600118c402213709bcf19f533c1b"
}
```

this is how I calculate the hash

```
$shared_key  =  'someKey';
$hash_params = [
   'Amount'       => $data['Amount'] , 
   'TransactionId' => $data['TransactionId'] , 
];
$hash_string = json_encode($hash_params) . $shared_key ;
$hash =  hash('sha256',    $hash_string  );    
if($hash != $data['PublicKey'] )
{
    die( "hash check failed");
}
```

In this scenario I need to sha256 this `$hash_string`

```
{"WithdrawAmount":5000.0000,"TransactionId":12345 }someKey
```

if it turns to

```
{"WithdrawAmount":"5000.0000","TransactionId":12345 }someKey
```

it'll give me a wrong hash

Comment: did you use number_format of php?

Comment: @Psycho that would convert it to string

Comment: A `float` value does not store a specific number of decimal places. `(float)500` is identical to `(float)500.0000`. The problem here is this hash that you need to create. Exactly how is that done? How do you know your result is incorrect? Are you comparing it with a hash provided by the software that generated the JSON? How did that treat this numeric value?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular i've added the hash calculation method at the end of my question , please take a look

Comment: If asking whoever provides this API(?) you are using there to _fix_ this utter nonsensical data format requirement on their end is not an option, then you might simply have to create the necessary "JSON string" yourself - manually, instead of using json_encode.

Comment: Still, the question is to which hash are you comparing? Why don't you hash the raw JSON string?

Comment: @Deckard i have to calculate the hash from some specific parameters , cant use all of them ... and i have to compare the generated hash against publicKey parameter (also sent by provider )

Comment: @CBroe that would be my last option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, there is no direct way to format the float value in the JSON string.

As an alternative to the replacement technique shown in Claudio's answer, here is a simple utility class that helps build the JSON string with the desired formatting:

```php
class JSONBuilder
{
    private $params = [];

    public function add($name, $value, $format='')
    {
        if($format)
            $encoded = sprintf($format, $value);
        else
            $encoded = json_encode($value);
        $this->params[] = sprintf('"%s":%s', $name, $encoded);
    }

    public function get()
    {
        return '{' . join(',', $this->params) . '}';
    }
}
```

Example:

```php
$b = new JSONBuilder();
$b->add('Amount', 5000.0, '%0.4f');
$b->add('Token', '6789');
$b->add('TransactionId', 12345);
echo $b->get();
```

Output:

```
{"Amount":5000.0000,"Token":"6789","TransactionId":12345}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an easy and simple way to perform a `json_encode`, of a Float value forcing 4 decimal places when the decimal part of the number is "0000", without manipulating the json string.

The `json_enconde` method has 2 predefined constants which helps us "almost" achieve the desired result, and these are the [JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK and JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) but normally the 0 are removed.

```
echo json_encode(["amount" => "5.0000"], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
```

Outputs: `{"amount":5.0}`

My solution, would be to perform the encoding using a unique string as amount value and then replace it using `str_replace` for the formatted amount like this:

```
$amount_needle = "###amount###";
$hash_params = [
   'Amount'       => $amount_needle, 
   'TransactionId' => $data['TransactionId'], 
];
$encoded_json = json_encode($hash_params);
$hash_string = str_replace("\"{$amount_needle}\"", sprintf('%0.4f', $data['Amount']), $encoded_json) . $shared_key ;
```

Comment: While it may not cause problems in this specific scenario, it is important to remind researchers that manually manipulating/mutating a json string will potentially damage it.  This kind of technique should only be entertained during extremely-fringe and desperate situations.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can do this with the `decimal` type instead of `double` or `float`. While my PHP knowledge is limited, it looks like the PHP world has something similar in BC Math and PHP Decimal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php
https://php-decimal.io/

Comment: Unfortunately the BC math operators return a `string` value, due to the limitations of floating point precision.

Answer (score -1):

Use built-in number_format function.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).